# package.json generation / npm unused packages

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, continuous-integration, npm

I'm introducing unit testing in my project and for this, I need to make myself a `package.json` file.

**First question** is, which `unit testing suite` are you using? I'm looking forward `mocha` which seem to be pretty much standard for `Node.js` projects.

**Second question** is: Is there any magical way of generating a `package.json` file? (for dependencies and versions)

**Third question** is: I've been testing a lot of `npm packages` while developing my project and now I'm stuck with a lot of probably unused packages. Is there any way to tell which one are useless? (I saw `npm list installed` which is useful though)

Comment: http://npmjs.org/doc/init.html is probably the easiest way to create a npm project. And I advise you ton read http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html and to inpire yourself from well used and tested packages such as express or npm itself.

Comment: You really should ask three separate questions.

Comment: Wow! So much good answers! Thanks to everybody, this is very very helpful! Keep'em coming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I am also using Mocha. It has code coverage, BDD, TDD, runs in browser. It is pretty complete and also heavily maintained by I think one of the most brilliant javascript/node.js programmers named TJ.
2. It is almost impossible to guess which version(s) to use. Because npm does not know which version breaks which dependencies. You could probably install all dependencies using something like [node-detective](https://github.com/substack/node-detective). Then you can just install them using npm.js from within javascript. Maybe I would like to tackle this in the future.
3. I would also probably delete all dependencies , next install needed dependencies back using step(2). But also disc-space is not such a big case anymore with the current HDs.

P.S: I think I also agree with Domenic

Answer (score 35):

1. I am using Mocha.
2. `npm init`
3. `npm ls` will list "extraneous" next to ones that are not in your package.json. But, it sounds like you don't have a package.json yet.

---

Basically, your workflow is very backward. Here is how it is intended to work:

1. Start a new project with `npm init`. It has no dependencies.
2. Oh, I want to start using a package, say `express`? Add it to `package.json` under dependencies, then run `npm install`.
3. Oh, I want to start using a package for development, say `mocha`? Add it to `package.json` under `devDependencies`, then run `npm install`.

You seem to have some existing code with manually-installed packages (via `npm install <packageName>`), which is a mess. I suggest starting over and following the above workflow.

Comment: You are totally right when you say that's backward. It was supposed to be a tiny test project but turned out way bigger and not for testing than I was expecting hehe. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can also do `npm install <packageName> --save` which will automatically add it to your `package.json`.  See here for more details: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html.  I find it easier than the workflow Domenic suggests above.

Comment: Also `--save-dev` for `devDependencies` (doc in the mentioned link)

Answer (score 21):

To answer the **third question**:

`npm prune`

will remove all installed modules that are no longer mentioned in your *package.json*.

---

And you should really have asked 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

1. I am using vows. It's pretty good, but not perfect. I have found unit testing in node to often be challenging because of async callbacks to dbs & such, and have mostly been testing top level functionality.
2. Here's your magic: [Managing Node.js Dependencies with Shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/).
3. The only way to know what packages you are using is to know. You can't generate this programmatically. My advice would be to remove packages aggressively, then retest all functionality - if it breaks, you'll know you need to reinstall one of your packages.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your **third question**, you can use [Sweeper](https://npmjs.org/package/sweeper) to list unused dependencies, and them remove them from your package.json. Just `npm install -g sweeper` then on your project directory call `sweeper` on the command line.